# What is the PHP equivalent of a VB dataset?

Tags: php, xml, vb.net, dataset

I'm working with an API that provides its examples in VB. It requires a Dataset to be passed within the XML.

The XML example looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItemsSResponse xmlns="http://ws.example.com">
      <GetItemSResult>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml
      </GetItemResult>
    </GetItemsSResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Their example for how the data set should be submitted is:

```
      Item List
      ("ItemID") = "abcde"          *
      ("ItemID") = "fghig"
      ("ItemID") = "klmno" 
      ("ItemID") = "pgrst"
```

I tried submitting as Json but the error implies that something is wrong with the data format.

Any ideas?

Comment: Json is not an XML.

Comment: Yes, but I figured maybe that's how it would be injected. What do you suggest?